# Train new dataset on transfer learning pre-trained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, imagenet

Code:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_util 
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from keras.applications import ResNet50
import numpy as np 
import argparse
import cv2
import time 

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image",required= True,help ="path of the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# orig = cv2.imread(args["image"]) #Opencv function to load a image
start_time = time.time()
image = image_util.load_img(args["image"],target_size=(224,224))
image = image_util.img_to_array(image)

#print("!!!!!.....!!!!")
print(image.shape)


image = np.expand_dims(image,axis=0) #(224,224,3) --> (1,224,224,3)
#print("!!!!!.....!!!!")
print(image.shape)
image = preprocess_input(image)

#Loading the model 
model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet")
pred = model.predict(image)
#print("111!!!!!.....!!!!")
#print(pred)
p = decode_predictions(pred)
#print("222!!!!!.....!!!!")
#print(p)

for (i,(imagenetID,label,prob)) in enumerate(p[0]):
    print("{}. {}: {:.2f}%".format(i+1, label, prob*100))

ans = p[0][0]
ans = ans[1]
print("THE PREDICTED IMAGE IS: "+ans)

orig = cv2.imread(args["image"]) #Opencv function to load a image
(imagenetID,label,prob) = p[0][0]
cv2.putText(orig, "{},{:.2f}%".format(label,prob*100),(10,30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.5,(0,0,0),1)
cv2.imshow("classification",orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This code works on imagenet weight and has a pre-trained model that can classify various images. 
I need to train a new object i.e my own dataset . (say for eg. apple).
What shall i do to update the weights adding my new dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to take only lower layers of a pretrained CNN (such as ResNet) and add new layers on top of the existing CNN.

Once you have your model, you probably should lock the pretrained layers at the beginning of the training so that you don't destroy those already trained weights and then after few cycles when the gradient stabilizes, you can unlock those layers and continue with training.

Easiest way to drop the top layers of the pretrained network is to set `include_top` argument to `False`.

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights="imagenet")
```

Then you can start adding your layers as usual, i.e. (`n_classes` refers to the number of classes that you want to classify)

```
my_hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(base_model)
# rest of the custom layers
...
output = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(previous_layer)
model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
```

To lock the pretrained layers at the beginning

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Then you can `compile` and `fit` your new model for a few epochs (even with larger learning rate), i.e.

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.2, momentum=0.9, decay=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, ...)
model.fit(...)
```

After the initial training is done, you can unlock the base layers and continue with the training (usually, you want to reduce the learning rate at this stage).

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=0.001)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
```

Note that you will have to run `compile` each time you lock or unlock those layers.

Comment: yeah. Thanks.
So is this the correct way to define :



(1)the final layer.




(2)model.fit(data,label) ... Data is my folder contains apple.. label = apple




Should the dataset be pre-labeled ?

Comment: Your output layers should be `Dense` and have `n` output neurons where `n` is the number of classes that you want to distinguish between (if you want to distinguish between 10 types of apples then you will need 10 output neurons). The dataset that contains your apples (the one that you will use for additional training) needs to have labels. This is no different than training your own network from scratch except for the fact that some of the weights (lower layers) have already been trained to perform similar task.

Comment: Is it possible to assign labels to the data while training? Like is there any inbuild parameter to assign?

Comment: No you can't do that during training. If you want to label the data, you need to do that prior to training. This is usually one of the hardest and most costly tasks. You would need an already trained classifier that would do that for you but then you probably wouldn't need to train one in the first place. If the dataset is not too large then you can try to do it manually yourself. There are also paid services that label your data such as AWS Ground Truth that are using manual labor combined with machine learning so that the price is lower compared to pure manual work.

Comment: After the inital training i.e your last second block of code. I have saved that model weight into a .h5 file . Now shld i retrain it by unlocking the layer like your last block of code ? 
How will I load and use the newly saved weight file ?

Comment: Locking and unlocking plays role only during training. It doesn't matter when the network is inferring the new values. To load the weights, you simply call `model.load_weights(...)`

Comment: 1) I have used your last second part of code and saved the weights. So there isn't any need of using the last part of code? 

2) After defining model.load_weights(..) i dont have complie and fit again rite? I can just call prediction statement ?

Comment: 1. If you don't want to train the whole model then you can skip the last part of the code (I would recommend to train it a bit but if it works without this step then feel free to omit it). 2 No, compile and fit are used only during the training. If you just want to make prediction then calling `compile` does nothing but you should definitely not call `fit` as it just starts a new training.

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! I appreciate you for your patience and time !